# How exactly do noise canceling headphones work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, process-engineering, computer-engineering

I purchased a pair of noise canceling headphones today and I was just wondering how exactly they are able to cancel out background noise?

Comment: This is a very well-documented question, with answers available all over the internet - as such it doesn't seem a good fit for this site.

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-cancelling_headphones then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control or even watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTx4JgYsW5s if you prefer not to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly they take the waveform of the ambient noise then produce the inverse waveform which is then generated. The two waveforms effectively cancel out leaving a much quieter ambient sound level.

The important part is to be able to separate the wanted "noise" (music or voices) from the unwanted noise.

A search will give you several results that will provide much more detail.